# How to get git.gitTagToVersionNumber value?

Tags: git, scala, sbt-native-packager, sbt-git

I am using https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git and https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html and would like to assign the value of `git.gitTagToVersionNumber` to my docker container.

I tried:

```
git.useGitDescribe := true

Docker / dockerAlias := DockerAlias(None, Some("zerocoder"), (packageName in Docker).value, git.gitTagToVersionNumber.value)
```

it does not work, because the type of the last argument of `DockerAlias` does not match.

How to get the value `git.gitTagToVersionNumber`?

I also tried:

git.useGitDescribe := true

```
git.formattedShaVersion := git.gitTagToVersionNumber.value("tag")
Docker / dockerAlias := DockerAlias(None, Some("zerocoder"), (packageName in Docker).value, git.gitDescribedVersion.value)
```

But it does not supply the desired value. I would like to tag my docker container for example with:

```
v0.2.0-2-g8d5cd83
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `sbt "show version"`?

Comment: I've got `[IJ]sbt:plugger> show version
[info] 0.2.0-2-g8d5cd83-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: But I would like to tag my package or docker container as follows: `v0.2.0-2-g8d5cd83`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of using `GitTagToVersionNumber`:

```
git.useGitDescribe := true
git.gitDescribePatterns := Seq("v*.*")
git.gitTagToVersionNumber := { tag :String =>

val branchTag = if (git.gitCurrentBranch.value == "master") "" else "-" + git.gitCurrentBranch.value
val uncommit = if (git.gitUncommittedChanges.value) "-U" else ""

tag match {
    case v if v.matches("v\\d+.\\d+") => Some(s"$v.0${branchTag}${uncommit}".drop(1))
    case v if v.matches("v\\d+.\\d+-.*") => Some(s"${v.replaceFirst("-",".")}${branchTag}${uncommit}".drop(1))
    case _ => None
}}
```

Don't forget you need to create a tag like v1.0 (`git tag v1.0` on your current branch) to see the above code work, since it is reading that from git. If you're testing this remotely don't forget to do `git push --tags`.

The example above provides:

- semver compatible natural versioning e.g 1.0.0 with minor/major sections.
- The Git SHA for an accurate understanding of what the code is doing. (excluding where the actual tag applies to the current SHA)
- The major part v1.0 comes from a manually create tag you need to make and the last part (e.g .3 in 1.0.3-xxx) comes from automatically counting the number of commits you are from the tag v1.0. Therefore it is less susceptible to human error than tagging every single minor release.
- It adds `-U` if the repository has modifications and therefore the code is not necessarily recreatable.
- It adds the branch name if you're not on the master branch.

This is a [complete working example](https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/rtp-email-lib/blob/68a2d6628d29b8b012a13b498320e11c2ac2aaa1/build.sbt) but maybe you haven't enabled the `GitVersioning` plugin in the project part of build.sbt`.

Comment: I've done as follows: `git.gitTagToVersionNumber := { tag: String =>
  if (tag.isEmpty)
    None
  else
    Some(tag.split("-").toList.head)
}` and I've got `v0.2.0-SNAPSHOT`. How to remove SNAPSHOT part? It should only show `v0.2.0`.

Comment: To remove snapshot add this line: `git.uncommittedSignifier := None`

Comment: @michael-mior: Please don't remove the link to the working example. The configuration requires files in project/ to fully understand the solution, so copying and pasting the linked contents into stackoverflow will leave many people without a full working example, and therefore unable to get the solution working.

Comment: @Philluminati The link is somewhat deceptive then since it says it leads to a complete working example. I've redone my edit to include the other minor fixes.